# Can TFS 2012 express be used with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2005, team-explorer

We are using VS2005 Professional edition and looking at source control options. Can TFS 2012 express be used with VS2005?

Comment: IMO, it's better to upgrade the 15 years old IDE:)

Comment: we have VS2010 professional, we are going to try upgrading that project to VS2010 and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the table which describes the level of support that's guaranteed with each client version in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops-2020#visual-studio-and-team-explorer

```
Visual Studio/Team Explorer                TFS 2012 support notes

    Visual Studio 2005            Version control available by using MSSCCI provider
```

Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21109

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?